# Stripe Connect - Multiple accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

I am collecting a payment using Stripe, and want to keep a portion, and send the rest onto another account from another organisation.

Stripe have told me that I have to connect an account. I have done this, Stripe gives me a link which the other organisation pastes into their browser, and all works. I can create a transfer linked to a payment intent.

But, when the link is pasted into the other organistions browser, this message is shown.
______ will be able to see your account data (such as all payment and payout history), including any data created by other business you've connected. They'll also be able to create new payments and take other actions for you.

This seems crazy - I just want to pay them some money, not ask them for full access.

Am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 0):

[Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/explore-connect-guide) is a product/tool that allows accounts to work together to provide goods and services to end customers.  There are a few different approaches to how this is configured based on your use case as well as whether you would be acting as the Platform (the one in control) or the Connect Account.

You should review the different [Connect Account Types](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) and determine what best matches your use case.  Some questions to consider are as follows:

- Who is interfacing with the end-customer (you or the other account)?
- Who is providing the product/service?
- Is this other account providing a service to you in exchange for a cut of the revenue?
- On what account should the transactions and customers be stored?

It sounds like, based on the warning message, you were creating the other account to be the Platform and you would be Connect Account.  In that cases the other account could make API calls on your behalf using your account token.  This would be normal if the other account is providing a service to you like funneling customers to you in some way.  A good way to quickly review what approach makes the most sense for your use case is to review the Funds Flow diagrams for the different types of Charges

- [Direct Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#flow-of-funds-with-fees)
- [Destination Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#flow-of-funds-app-fee)
- [Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#collecting-fees)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a way we can just pay another account? I have their account id, I just want to pass them some money.

Comment: If you don't want to use Connect then the other account would have to set you up as a Customer and make a Charge that you would pay.  In general, Stripe is focused on merchant collecting money, not paying it out.